# DataBinding over BaseActivity

Tags: java, android, data-binding

First, I tried all the solutions that were proposed on `Stackoverflow` but didn't work for me. So I am having a trouble while using `DataBinding` over my `Base Activity`. I am getting

> Attempt to read from field
>   'com.mobilemovement.bestcoin.databinding.ToolbarLayoutBinding
>   com.mobilemovement.bestcoin.databinding.ActivityHolderBinding.ahToolbarLayout'
>   on a null object reference

BaseActivity.java

```
public abstract class BaseActivity<B extends ViewDataBinding> extends 
AppCompatActivity {

protected B dataBinding;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private NavigationView mNavigationView;
private Toolbar mToolbar;

protected void bindView(Toolbar toolbar, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, NavigationView navigationView) {
    dataBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, setLayoutResourceIdentifier());

    mToolbar = toolbar;
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mNavigationView = navigationView;
    setupDrawerContent();

    mDrawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();

    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class HolderActivity extends BaseActivity<ActivityHolderBinding> {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    bindView(dataBinding.ahToolbarLayout.toolbar,
            dataBinding.dlHolderActivity,
            dataBinding.nvItemHolder);
}
```

I could use DataBinding without BaseActivity so I mean my layouts and IDs are correct however when I switched to BaseActivity, I got error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: you have `bindView(dataBinding....` in derived class and `dataBinding = DataBindingUtil...` in `bindView` base class ... how this should work?